# How to redeploy Heroku review apps from git command line without pushing new commits?

Tags: heroku, deployment, command-line, heroku-review-app

We are trying to find a way to redeploy Heroku review apps from the git command line without pushing new commits. It seems the only way to do this is by pushing an empty commit since review apps deploy automatically on push to github. I know there is a manual way to do this in the Heroku console, but we were hoping to streamline things since we are able to set the config via command line.

Suggestions I tried:

1. heroku builds:create --app {your-app-name}
2. git push testbranch:main
3. heroku restart (restarts dynos, but doesn't redeploy which is necessary to update backend we are pointing to)
4. heroku plugins:install heroku-releases-retry
   heroku releases:retry --app {your-app}